# Parent div must be scrollable and child div must overflow in parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem,
Parent div with fixed height 90vh.
It has 2 inner divs both are exceeding parent div, their height is morethan 90vh ,
Both in flex direction- column, mobile view,

And the inner div height is not fixed and varies, so i wants to show these inner divs in parent div. With scroll ,
Inner divs must not scroll, parent div must scroll

How to acheive this

Comment: Welcome @ArunSunny to StackOverflow .. I would suggest that you provide some code samples so that we easier would be able to provide you with the help you want.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow-y: auto` in your parent `div`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want. Try this.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #e5e9ec;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

.inner {
  height: 600px;
}

.inner:first-child {
  background: #ddd;
}

.inner:last-child {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```